# How can I represent current JSON scheme in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, json, cocoa-touch

Everything messed up in my head. enum, NSObject, custom interface and so on...
All I need is to declare data type in Objective C for representing this JSON collection:

```
{
 "firstName": "John",
 "lastName" : "Smith",
 "age"      : 25,
 "address"  :
 {
     "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
     "city"         : "New York",
     "state"        : "NY",
     "postalCode"   : "10021"
 },
 "phoneNumber":
 [
     {
       "type"  : "home",
       "number": "212 555-1234"
     },
     {
       "type"  : "fax",
       "number": "646 555-4567"
     }
 ]
```

}

This is example from wikipedia JSON article. So I need an explanation about how can I put all this data in collection (or custom type or something else, I don't know).

For example I need 1000 instances of "phonebook" collection to store **and change** information about 1000 people. I need to know how can I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example for firstname and address:

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                  JSONObjectWithData:data 
                      options:kNilOptions 
                      error:&error];

NSString *firstname = [json objectForKey:@"firstname"]; 
NSDictionary *address = [json objectForKey:@"address"];
```

more here: http://caydenliew.com/2011/11/json-in-ios-5/

Comment: What does that mean? I am weak at finding errors in code because I just learning. But can you explain this code: `NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                      JSONObjectWithData:data 
                      options:kNilOptions 
                      error:&error];`

Comment: that function is to decode json data into objective-c object. the 'data' is actually json data from a json string. you encode a json string into data like this: NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; then use the NSJSONSerialization to decode the Json object.

Comment: I can't get it working. I have errors like **No know class method for selector 'JSONObjectWithData:'**. I was trying to use my returnData (NSData) with json data for parsing. Not succeed.

Comment: are you using IOS5? NSJSONSerialization is only supported in IOS5 onwards, if you are in IOS4.3 and below, you can use the library [SBSJSON](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/)

Comment: Yes, I am using iOS5. Maybe you could make a simple project for showing this? I have not found a link to github in your article. That could be the eaziest way to figure it out for me.

Comment: great :) you shld also check that if the device if ios 4.3 and below, use the SBJson library instead, or it won't work.